# Error in JDK Installation in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

I downloaded the jdk7 update 21 tar.gz.
 I then extracted it and created a folder jvm  under /usr/lib  . Then when i tried to move it  to /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0 it showed me permission denied.
what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

System drive won't let anyone to copy/paste anything in it without permission. If you tried to move using terminal than before use any command enter as root user

```
sudo su
```

It tell you to enter your password. Type it and press enter than use move command.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to install Java 7 would be :

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```